# Woocommerce lost/forget password API for Android

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need your help in making an `API` for `Android` that implements forget password in `WooCommerce`. I want to use `retrieve_password()` which is documented [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcode_My_Account.html#2-370) and does exactly what I want to do.

What I did so far is

forgetpwd.php

```
<?php 
    $ulog=$_POST['user_login'];
    require'class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php '';
    $fp=new WC_Shortcode_My_Account();

    $verify->retreive_password($ulog);

    if(){
        $final['message'] = "incorrect username or password";
    }
    else
    {
        $final['message'] = "success";
    }
    print_r(json_encode($final));
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want to implement retrieve_password() from  https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcode_My_Account.html#2-370  passing  $_POST['user_login'] parameters and process it in forgetpwd. php with if statement and returning $final messages.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. I recommend reading the help section if you're unsure https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: i know what stackoverflow is I am absolutely clear. see the code i have wrote there it isn't displaying anything all

Comment: Your question is missing essential details. Such as the desired output, what you've tried, what error message or behavior you are currently getting. I recommend reading the help section if you're unsure stackoverflow.com/help/asking